# Cloud functions for multiples files gcp bucket events

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm creating a Cloud Function in GCP to automatically resize images uploaded to a bucket and transfer them to another bucket. Since the images arrive in batches and one folder might contain hundreds or thousands of images, is it better to incorporate in the code the ability to deal with the multiple files or is better to let cloud functions be triggered on every image uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel processing is really powerful with serverless product because it scales up and down automatically according to your workloads.

If you can receive thousands of image in few seconds, the serverless product scalability can have difficulties and you can loose some messages (serverless scale up quickly, but it's not magic!!)

A better solution is to publish the [Cloud Storage event in PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). Like that you can retry easily the failed messages.

If you continue to increase the number of image, or if you want to optimize cost, I recommend you to have a look on Cloud Run.

You can plug PubSub push subscription to Cloud Run. The power of Cloud Run is the capacity to process several HTTP requests (PubSub push message -> Cloud Storage events) on the same instance, and therefore to process concurrently several image on the same instance. If the conversion process is compute intensive, you can have up to 4 CPUs on a Cloud Run instance.

And, as Cloud Functions, you pay only the number of active (being processing request) instances. With Cloud Functions you can process 1 request at a time, therefore 1 instance per file. With Cloud Run you can process up to 1000 concurrent request and therefore your can reduce up to 1000 time the number of instances, and thus your cost. However, take care of the CPU required for you processing, if it's compute intensive, you can't process 1000 images at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> The `finalize` event is sent when a new object is created (or an existing object is overwritten, and a new generation of that object is created) in the bucket.

A new function will be triggered for each object uploaded. You can try compressing all those images in a `ZIP` file on client, upload it so it'll trigger only 1 function, then upload images back to storage after unzipping them. But make sure you don't hit any limits mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

Comment: Thanks for the insights! Would it be better to use Cloud Run instead?

Comment: @Dudes I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. If I need to process all the images before uploading to Storage, I usually run them through a server running on [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) (you can use Cloud Run). This also helps in preventing user from uploading a large amount of data directly to storage and there are not timeouts like Cloud functions.

Comment: Besides, I can only call a function for 1000 times or is 1000 calls at the same time?

Comment: @Dudes What do you mean by that? Those functions will be triggered when the objects are completely uploaded.

Comment: My question was more regarding the 1000 calls quota. The 1000 limit is simultaneously calls or 1000 times since the creation of the function?